# How to spread the data in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i'm working on spread r equivalent in pandas my dataframe looks like below

```
Name age Language year   Period
Nik   18  English  2018  Beginer
John  19  French   2019  Intermediate
Kane  33  Russian  2017  Advanced
xi    44  Thai     2015  Beginer
```

and looking for output like this

```
Name age Language Beginer Intermediate Advanced
Nik   18  English  2018
John  19  French            2019
Kane  33  Russian                        2017
John   44  Thai     2015
```

my code

```py
pd.pivot(x1,values='year', columns=['Period'])
```

i'm getting only these columns Beginer,Intermediate,Advanced not the entire dataframe
while reshaping it i tried using index but says no duplicates in index.
So i created new index column but still not getting entire dataframe

Comment: Does this suffice: ``df.pivot(["Name", "age", "Language"], "Period", "year").reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)``

Answer (score 0):

One way you can get to the equivalent of **R's** `spread` function using `pd.pivot_table`:

If you don't mind about the index, you can use `reset_index()` on the newly created df:

```
new_df = (pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Name','age','Language'],columns='Period',values='year',aggfunc='sum')).reset_index()
```

which will get you:

```
Period  Name  age Language  Advanced  Beginer  Intermediate
0       John   19   French       NaN      NaN        2019.0
1       Kane   33  Russian    2017.0      NaN           NaN
2        Nik   18  English       NaN   2018.0           NaN
3         xi   44     Thai       NaN   2015.0           NaN
```

**EDIT**

**If you have many columns in your dataframe and you want to include them in the reshaped dataset:**

1. Grab in a list the columns to be used in pivot table (i.e. Period and year)
2. Grab all the other columns in your dataframe in a list (using `not in`)
3. Use the index_cols as index in the `pd.pivot_table()` command

```
non_index_cols = ['Period','year'] # SPECIFY THE 2 COLUMNS IN THE PIVOT TABLE TO BE USED
index_cols = [i for i in df.columns if i not in non_index_cols] # GET ALL THE REST IN A LIST
new_df = (pd.pivot_table(df, index=index_cols,columns='Period',values='year',aggfunc='sum')).reset_index()
```

The new_df, will include all the columns of your initial dataframe.

Comment: Had 30 columns do i need to specify in index like that or any other alternate for this

Comment: Yes I believe you have to specify. This is basically acts like a pivot table in excel.

Comment: Check the answer now. If you have many columns and you don't want to type 1 by 1 as index, you can do the above trick.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you could do something like this:

```
# create dummy columns
res = pd.get_dummies(df['Period']).astype(np.int64)
res.values[np.arange(len(res)), np.argmax(res.values, axis=1)] = df['year']

# concat and drop columns
output = pd.concat((df.drop(['year', 'Period'], 1), res), 1)

print(output)
```

**Output**

```
   Name  age Language  Advanced  Beginner  Intermediate
0   Nik   18  English         0      2018             0
1  John   19   French         0         0          2019
2  Kane   33  Russian      2017         0             0
3    xi   44     Thai         0      2015             0
```

If you want to match the exact same output, convert the column to categorical first, and specify the order:

```
# encode as categorical
df['Period'] = pd.Categorical(df['Period'], ['Beginner', 'Advanced', 'Intermediate'], ordered=True)

# create dummy columns
res = pd.get_dummies(df['Period']).astype(np.int64)
res.values[np.arange(len(res)), np.argmax(res.values, axis=1)] = df['year']

# concat and drop columns
output = pd.concat((df.drop(['year', 'Period'], 1), res), 1)

print(output)
```

**Output**

```
   Name  age Language  Beginner  Advanced  Intermediate
0   Nik   18  English      2018         0             0
1  John   19   French         0         0          2019
2  Kane   33  Russian         0      2017             0
3    xi   44     Thai      2015         0             0
```

Finally if you want to replace the 0, with missing values, add a third step:

```
# create dummy columns
res = pd.get_dummies(df['Period']).astype(np.int64)
res.values[np.arange(len(res)), np.argmax(res.values, axis=1)] = df['year']
res = res.replace(0, np.nan)
```

**Output** *(with missing values)*

```
   Name  age Language  Beginner  Advanced  Intermediate
0   Nik   18  English    2018.0       NaN           NaN
1  John   19   French       NaN       NaN        2019.0
2  Kane   33  Russian       NaN    2017.0           NaN
3    xi   44     Thai    2015.0       NaN           NaN
```